Is it possible to tag another person with @username in MS teams chat bot one to one chat?
I have a MS teams chat bot. When in a one to one chat with the bot, I need to tag another user with @username so that I can uniquely identify the user tagged. This is possible when in group chat by mentioning chat bot first and then user name with @ symbol, like @botname @username. Is there any way I can achieve this in one to one chat?
Bot framework is .net8 and using MS Teams Toolkit for VS.

Currently it's not possible to tag another person with @username in MS teams chat bot one to one chat.
To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams Feedback Portal.
